# Sum of time difference and amount of switches

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I have an application for internet of things products these products report in an interval or on error to the server. now I want to create a report on how stable the products are and I have the following data.

```
ID ReportTime (DateTime)   InError
1  2017-17-10 03:00:00     False
1  2017-17-10 03:30:00     True
1  2017-17-10 04:00:00     False
1  2017-17-10 05:00:00     False
1  2017-17-10 06:00:00     True
1  2017-17-10 07:00:00     True
1  2017-17-10 08:00:00     False
```

I want to know how long the product has been InError and how often so with the above example it should return
2 Times with a value of 02:30:00

How can I do this using EF/linq or, if necessary, SQL?

Comment: It looks like the product was InError 3 times. How do you come to 2 times?

Comment: what is the database you have if you plan to do it in SQL?

Comment: database is MSSQL, the product is in error 2 times because only on every switch between a false and true record it should count a new state.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in EF or linq but if you are using a MySql for example you can do it with one query like that (using a temporary variable). This is more like a pseudo code you need to tweak with it for a bit expecially for date calculation but it shows the idea.

```
 SELECT  InError,sum(errorDuration) from (
   SELECT ID,
          ReportTime ,
          InError ,
          @prevReportTime :=ReportTime,
          ReportTime-@prevReportTime as errorDuration
   FROM thetable
    JOIN (SELECT @prevReportTime  := ( SELECT min(ReportTime) from the table) ) t
    ORDER BY ReportTime
) group by InError
```

In SQL server you can do a similar thing using LAG function over by ReportTime :
Something like

```
 ReportTime - LAG(ReportTime) OVER (ORDER BY ReportTime) errorDuration
```

Or you can use rank() and temporary table:

```
 select  rank() OVER (ORDER BY ReportTime) as 'Rank', value into temp1 from theTable

 select t1.inError, t1.ReportTime- t2.ReportTime as duration from temp1 t1, temp1 t2 
 where t1.Rank = t2.Rank - 1
```

The idea is to get the previous time and for each row to have the duration since previous report. After that when you have this "view" you just sum that duration and group by InError to get the duration of the error state and of the normal state. Most databases allow you to do that but it usually involves specific functions

Answer (score 0):

Try this [solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fCJQS2). It is important to `Insert` `start` item not `inError` state into `data` at first position, because first `inError` row can also be first among whole set of rows and at this case you should have previous row for it, to perform subtraction and valid `switches` calculation:

```
var start = DateTime.Today;
//for example, fetch data for current day
var data = db.Table.Where(x => x.Datetime >= start && x.Datetime < tomorrow).ToList();

data.Insert(0, new Log { InError = false, DateTime = start });

var time = new TimeSpan(data.Where(x => x.InError).Sum(x =>            
    (x.DateTime - data[data.IndexOf(x) - 1].DateTime).Ticks
));

var switches = data.Where(x => x.InError && !data[data.IndexOf(x) - 1].InError).Count();
```